# Randomly data save in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, find, random

I created randomly data in SQL Server and I save `RAND()` number.

I am looking for same datas but i can't find again with `RAND()` number.

I have a like this code:

```
SELECT 
    name, surname, RAND()
FROM 
    customers
ORDER BY 
    RAND()
```

RAND()=0,366577559363461

How to find same data?

Comment: If your looking for same data, then you should search your table like this after you save your data into the table using rand() function. select * from customers where col3=RAND()..

Comment: I'm so sorry but i don't understand. I have got just RAND() number.I want to find with this number. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Rand() function will always give you a different number every time you run your query. You cannot rely on it. The best way is to have a placeholder for your data(temporary table) where you can save your random data for future access.